# Foursquare API Login - Inadequate privileges level

Tags: api, authentication, foursquare

I am having this problem while building one iPhone app that connects to Foursquare. Login works for other accounts, but for one, I get this error in the console:

{"error":{"statuscode":400,"errormessage":"Foursquare authentication failed. Inadequate privileges level"}}

I have googled it without any luck. Any ideas what could be causing this?

Best,
Mladjo

Comment: What action are you calling that returns that error?